# What is the oldest "original" anime series?

Tags: anime-history

Note: I am not asking about the oldest anime series. I am talking about "original anime series" i.e. anime series not adapted/based from manga/LN/VN/games but an original story that went straight into animation and then to the general public.

From my knowledge, the earliest I know is [*Mobile Suit Gundam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam) (1979-80) which makes it approxiamtely 41 years old. Are there any original anime series older than Mobile Suit Gundam?

Comment: Highly-related/possible dupe: [What is the first-ever produced anime and manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3408/2516): *Otogi Manga Calendar* (1961) as the first original anime series.

Answer (score 2):

Sazae-san began airing in Japan in October 1969 and holds the Guinness World Record for the longest-running animated television series

Comment: *Sazae-san* originated from a manga series. Is the anime series of *Sazae-san* an original series, not an adaptation of the manga?

Answer (score 1):

Humanoid Monster Bem was broadcast in 1968, it's one of the oldest animes made with no prior screenplay